# How to secure activation of Android app?

Tags: android, encryption, cryptography

I have an android app that needs to be Activated to work on devices. The process of Activation is by sending an encrypted key by sms and getting an encrypted reply by sms to activate the app. Assume that encryption/decryption is safe. The problem is that I have to store the app status (activated/not activated/activation failed) and read it on each start up to see that app is activated or not. preferences and sqlite database are not secure. What is the best approach to save this state?

Comment: If neither preferences or sqlite are secure enough for your purposes, then nothing stored on the device will be. Server-side is the way to go.

Comment: Is there a way to encrypt sqlite databse or preferences file?

Answer (score 6):

Keep the activated state on your server, and check it on startup.

There is no truly secure storage on Android devices. Users can get to, and modify, whatever they want, given modest technical skills. If you do not want users messing with the data, do not put it on their device.

Comment: I can rely on Internet connectivity so the activation process is done with SMS. Is there a way to encrypt sqlite database or preferences file?

Comment: @AliBehzadianNejad: Not to protect against users. The encryption key and algorithm will be in your app. Anyone can get at your app and get the key and algorithm. Hence, if you can decrypt it, so can anyone else who wants to.